# Update class on one progress bar where there are multiple progress bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having trouble updating the class on bootstrap progress bar.

I have multiple progress bars on a single page and I want to only update the class on one at the time if it goes over for example 20%. From "progress progress-success" to "progress progress-danger"

[image]

I have tried many variations, my code looks now like this where I'm trying to set unique id on
every bar by ng-repeat (AngularJS).

Javascript :

```
$scope.result = ProjectServices.projects().get(function(d) {
$scope.tasktime = []
  console.log($scope.result.Tasks);
  var tasks = $scope.result.Tasks;

  for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    var prosent = ( tasks[i].EstimatedTimeLeft / tasks[i].EstimatedTime ) * 100;
    console.log(prosent);
    var extra = '#bar' + i;
    if(prosent > 20 ) {
      $(extra).removeClass("progress progress-success");
      $(extra).addClass("progress progress-danger");

    }
    $scope.tasktime.push(prosent);
  }
```

HTML : note $index is angularjs syntax to generate numbers from 0...?

```
 <div id="bar{{$index}}" class="progress progress-success">
    <div  class="bar" style="width:{{tasktime[$index] | number:2}}%">{{tasktime[$index] | number:1}}% </div>
  </div>
```

But it dosent seem to pick up the element, because I know it goes into the if statement.

My extra variable `var extra = '#bar' + i;` dosen't seem to be legit either any idead how to update single progress bar and generate id for the jQuery selector command?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap ?

Comment: It's is in the project, but not using it for this at the moment, is it easier ?

Comment: It is worlds easier.  The angular bootstrap directive for the progress bar is what you will want to use.   Would you accept an answer using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this example you would be better served to use the `ng-class` attribute and let angular make the class changes instead of forcing jquery into your controller which generally you wouldn't want to do:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass

```
<div id="bar{{$index}}" class="progress " ng-class='{"progress-success":tasktime[$index].prosent<=20,"progress-danger":tasktime[$index].prosent>20}'>
    <div  class="bar" style="width:{{tasktime[$index] | number:2}}%">{{tasktime[$index] | number:1}}% </div>
  </div>
```

A quick note I realized the `prosent` isn't defined, however you could just as easily define a function in your controller:

```
$scope.prosent = function(item) {
  return ( item.EstimatedTimeLeft / item.EstimatedTime ) * 100
}
```

And the html would be:  `ng-class='{"progress-success":prosent(item)` or `prosent(tasktime[$index]` depending on your repeater/etc.

Lastly, it seems like perhaps you have not shared all of your code..  I would set up an ng-repeat and do it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='task in tasktime' class='progress' ng-class='{"progress-success":task.prosent<=20,"progress-danger: task.prosent>20'>
  <div  class="bar" style="width:{{task | number:2}}%">{{task | number:1}}% </div>
etc
```

Comment: Alternatively there is the angular bootstrap that also has a progress bar that might be better to use with angular.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I'm traveling. I used ng-class to solve this. Thank you!